# How to recognize WPF drawing visuals in UIAutomation?

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-ui-automation

Our application has a canvas, to which we add the drawing visuals (like lines, polygons etc)

```
// sample code

var canvas = new Canvas(); // create canvas
var visuals = new VisualCollection(canvas); // link the canvas to the visual collection
visuals.Add(new DrawingVisual()); // add the visuals to the canvas
visuals.Add(new DrawingVisual());
```

Our goal is to add these visuals to the canvas via automation and validate that they are properly added. We use a framework that is based on Microsoft's UIAutomation.

When using a tool like "Inspect" to inspect the visual structure, I couldnt locate the canvas. Did some research and figured out that you need to override the `OnCreateAutomationPeer` method from `UIElement`, and return applicable `AutomationPeer` object to be able to be able to see that in automation.

Made the change and now I can see the canvas, however I cant still see any of the visuals added under the canvas.

**Can anyone help me understand what the issue is?**

Things tried / alternatives:

1. Tried to employ the OnCreateAutomationPeer technique, but the
   `DrawingVisual`s dont derive from `UIElement`, and I cant add `UIElement`s
   to `Canvas.VisualCollection`.
2. Image recognition is an option, but we
   are trying to avoid it for performance/maintenance considerations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only UIElement can be seen from UI Automation (like you have seen, OnCreateAutomationPeer starts from this class, not from the Visual class).

So you need to add UIElement (or derived like FrameworkElement) to the canvas, if you want it to be usable by UIAutomation.

You can create your own class like described here: [Using DrawingVisual Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx) or with a custom UserControl or use an existing one that suits your need but it *must* derive from UIElement somehow.

Once you have a good class, you can use the default AutomationPeer or override the method and adapt more closely.

If you want to keep Visual objects, one solution is to modify the containing object (but it still needs to derive from UIElement). For example, here if I follow the article in the link, I can write a custom containing object (instead of a canvas of your sample code so you may have to adapt slightly) like this:

```
public class MyVisualHost  : UIElement
{
    public MyVisualHost()
    {
        Children = new VisualCollection(this);
    }

    public VisualCollection Children { get; private set; }


    public void AddChild(Visual visual)
    {
        Children.Add(visual);
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return Children.Count; }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return Children[index];
    }

    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new MyVisualHostPeer(this);
    }

    // create a custom AutomationPeer for the container
    private class MyVisualHostPeer : UIElementAutomationPeer
    {
        public MyVisualHostPeer(MyVisualHost owner)
            : base(owner)
        {
        }

        public new MyVisualHost Owner
        {
            get
            {
                return (MyVisualHost)base.Owner;
            }
        }

        // a listening client (like UISpy is requesting a list of children)
        protected override List<AutomationPeer> GetChildrenCore()
        {
            List<AutomationPeer> list = new List<AutomationPeer>();
            foreach (Visual visual in Owner.Children)
            {
                list.Add(new MyVisualPeer(visual));
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

    // create a custom AutomationPeer for the visuals
    private class MyVisualPeer : AutomationPeer
    {
        public MyVisualPeer(Visual visual)
        {
        }

        // here you'll need to implement the abstrat class the way you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Simon. Using DrawingVisuals but not UIElements on canvas was conscious decision to help with performance. Our app has a ton shapes added to the canvas. I am wondering if there is another way out of this.

Comment: Thanks again Simon. This should work. I had something on the similar lines, I was passing the visuals inside the OnCreateAutomationPeer and I was trying keep up with the visual collection changes, and was kind of stuck there. You solved that problem with the Children property added under owner.

Comment: @SimonMourier : I am curious... your preceding post states that *Only UIElement can be seen from UI Automation*. `Canvas` (and children like: `Path`) inherit from `UIElement`, so why aren't they visible to Microsoft's UIA?

Comment: @Pressacco - "Can" doesn't mean "Will". If a class derives from UIElement, it "can" be visible from UIA but it "will" only if it (or its hierarchy) overrides OnCreateAutomationPeer and returns something non null. Canvas doesn't, Panel doesn't, FrameworkElement doesn't. In general, most Controls and Documents do. Canvas is not a Control. But you can derive and override yourself

Comment: @SimonMourier : Thanks for the clarification: "can vs. will". Much appreciated.